# Data is not validated in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to pass the data to a serializer like the following:

```
myDict = {
    "invoice_date": "2021-02-24T11:44:13+05:30",
    "invoice_number": "12",
    "vendor": "4",
    "amount": "12",
    "gst": "12",
    "total_amount": "14",
    "transaction_type": "Allot",
    "status": "Hold",
    "transactions": [
        {
            "t_no": 47,
            "f_mile": "45",
            "long_haul": "45",
            "l_mile": "45",
            "labour": "45",
            "others": "54",
            "a_t_no": 47,
        },
        {
            "t_no": 102,
            "f_mile": "12",
            "long_haul": "12",
            "l_mile": "21",
            "labour": "21",
            "others": "21",
            "a_t_no": 102,
        },
    ],
    "owner": 2,
}
```

But when I check the validated data in the serialzer it shows it without the `transactions` data:

```
{'invoice_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 24, 6, 14, 13, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'invoice_number': '12', 'amount': 12, 'gst': 12, 'total_amount': 14, 'status': 'Hold', 'transaction_type': 'Allot', 'vendor': <Vendor: Vendor object (4)>, 'owner': <User: yantraksh>}
```

so I tried to check the initial data that is being passed to the serializer :

```
<QueryDict: {
"invoice_date": ["2021-02-24T11:44:13+05:30"],
"invoice_number": ["12"],
"vendor": ["4"],
"amount": ["12"],
"gst": ["12"],
"total_amount": ["14"],
"transaction_type": ["Allot"],
"status": ["Hold"],
"transactions": [
    '[{"t_no":47,"f_mile":"45","long_haul":"45","l_mile":"45","labour":"45","others":"54","a_t_no":47},{"t_no":102,"f_mile":"12","long_haul":"12","l_mile":"21","labour":"21","others": "21","a_t_no":102}]'
],
"owner": [2],
```

}>

It shows that the transaction data is being passed as a string, what should I change it to in order to get it as validated data ?

Comment: did your serializer define a `transactions` field?

Comment: Since that's a query dict in the last exhibit, how are you "passing that data" in particular? I.e. what do you do with `myDict`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "evidence" in that QueryDict (namely strings wrapped in lists) it sounds like you're not submitting the data as JSON.

You can't use regular HTML form data to submit structured data, you'll need to post JSON data.

Comment: I am trying t0 do this in the django rest framework